# Office 365 APIs Add User using Office 365 API Tools - Preview

Tags: office-365-developer, office365apis

when call method

```
        await client.Users.AddUserAsync(newUser, false);
```

then in view

[image]

Comment: Seems you already have a user with same LoginName as the one you try to create?

Comment: At least paste good chunk of request and response?

Comment: @RobertLindgren in User object can't find LoginName Property

Comment: It's what's called UserPrincipalName in your code

Comment: @RobertLindgren in User object AssignedPlans and AssignedLicenses readonly Properties how can assign both?

Comment: That seems like a different question than what you are painting above

Comment: @RobertLindgren yes i solve the problem and user added but i can't assign Plans

Comment: If you solve a problem you should post the solution here. New question = new question

Comment: solution is LoginName is reapted